# PHP Проблема с конвертацией PDF в Изображение (на выходе только текст)

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, imagick

Конвертирую первую страницу PDF файла в JPG средствами ImageMagick. Использую эту либу https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image

```
public function convert($source)
{

    $pdf = new Pdf($source);
    $pdf->setPage(1)
    ->setCompressionQuality(50)
    ->setOutputFormat($this->format)
    ->saveImage($this->getSavePath($source));
    return $this->getUrl($source);
}
```

На локальном сервере все работает и на тестовом работает, а на продакшене конвертирует только текст. В тех местах где были фото в документе на выходе пустые области.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так.

```
$num_page = 9;
$img = new Imagick(dirname(__FILE__)."/test.pdf[$num_page]");
$img->setImageFormat('jpg');
$img->writeImage(dirname(__FILE__)."/out.jpg");
```

Comment: Этот вариант ничем не отличается, в методах класса происходит все то же самое. ПРоблема была в устаревшем ПО.